# How to check the correct order of months in unix?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I am writing a code to get the data between two times present in a log file. My input will be

```
./filename Apr 10 16 02:07:20 Jul 11 16 11:07:30
```

where I am storing `"Apr 10 16 02:07:20"` in `$StartTime` variable and `"Jul 11 16 11:07:30"` in `$EndTime` variable as follows,

```
StartTime="$1 $2 $3 $4"
EndTime="$5 $6 $7 $8"
```

If my input is `./filename Jul 11 16 11:07:30 Apr 10 16 02:07:20`, then it should display an error saying StartTime cannot be greater than EndTime.

I am using the following logic,

```
if [[ "$StartTime" > "$EndTime" ]] 
then
{
echo "Error: StartTime cannot be greater than EndTime"
exit 
}
fi
```

But it is taking months in alphabetical order, April,August,December... and considering August is greater than May. How to sort the months with number?Please help.

Comment: You should be using awk for this, not a shell script. Shell is for sequencing calls to tools, not for manipulating text - that's awk's job. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). If you post a new question with concise, testable sample input and expected output then someone will be able to help you do whatever you are doing the right way.

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `date`:

```
$ StartTime=$(date --date="$1 $2 $4 $3" +%s)
$ echo $StartTime
1460243240
$ EndTime=$(date --date="$5 $6 $8 $7" +%s)
$ echo $EndTime
1468224450
$ your_script_above.sh
$ echo $?
0
```

Man date:
- - 
    %s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC